# Observing a generic class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI.

I have a button struct that contains the following property:

```
struct CircleTextButton: View {

  @ObservedObject var controlModel:MyModelA
  // bla bla
```

I would like to be able to reuse this button. So, I need this controlModel property to be able to assume other values, beyond MyModelA. For example, MyModelB

How should I declare this?

I have tried

```
@ObservedObject var controlModel:Any
```

but I get

> Property type 'Any' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your view generic over the type of `controlModel` and constraint `Model` to be `ObservableObject`.

```
struct CircleTextButton<Model: ObservableObject>: View {

  @ObservedObject var controlModel: Model
  ...
```

To create a specific button with a specific model, you need to do

```
let button = CircleTextButton(controlModel: MyModelA())
```

Comment: ok, but how is each model declared? I mean I can have controlModelA, controlModelB, etc.

Comment: this code does not compile. Same error: Property type 'Model' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'

Comment: @Ronnie check my updated answer, now it should compile